# Back press in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In a fragment on `ViewPager` I have `ListView` and `GridView`. Initially I hide `ListView` and show `GridView`. When I click an item in `GridView`, I hide `GridView` and show `ListView`. Now I want to return to the previous state when I click again: hide the `ListView` and show the `GridView`. How do I do this? I tried with method `onBackPressessed` in activity:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        int count = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        if (count == 3) {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
                super.onBackPressed();
            } else {
                // Toast.makeText(this, "BACK",
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (!flag) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Nhấn Back một lần nữa để thoát",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            flag = true;
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(2000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    }).start();
                } else {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
            }

        } else....
```

But I do not know how to call it in fragment. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can call onBackPressed with the hosting activity. Try this in your fragment:

```
getActivity().onBackPressed();
```

That will call the activity's onBackPressed() method, which will do what you want.